# How to create ComboBox in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I want to create a function which takes two arguments

1. A String value (name)
2. An array of String objects

The function creates LWUIT Combobox with these two parameters and returns a ComboBox varialble...

I have written following code ...

```
 public void createComboxBox(String recStoreName,String [] values){
    comboBox = new ComboBox(recStoreName, values);
    surveyForm.addComponent(comboBox);

}
```

Comment: 1. That's a method, not a function. 2. You must "return comboBox;" at the end of the method. 3. Must declare return type as ComboBox instead of void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   //create a form and set its title
    Form f = new Form("Simple ComboBox");

    //set layout manager for the form
    //f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //set form background colour
    f.getStyle().setBgColor(0xd5fff9);
    .
    .
    .
```

The first two lines of code are quite self-explanatory and should be familiar to AWT/Swing developers. The third line sets the background color attribute for the form.

The combo box is also instantiated in a similar manner:

```
    // Create a set of items
    String[] items = { "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow" };

    //create a combobox with String[] items
    ComboBox combobox = new ComboBox(items);
```

---

**Resource**

- [Using Styles, Themes, and Painters with LWUIT](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/09/23/using-styles-themes-painters-with-lwuit.html)

---

**Also See**

- [The Lightweight User Interface Toolkit (LWUIT): An Introduction](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/lwuit_intro/)

Comment: thanks Jigar.... I have done something similar ... problem is I dont know how to add the recStoreInformation (the first parameter) with the ComboBox.....

Comment: `recStoreInformation ` did you mean instance of `RecordStore`  ?

Comment: He need like passing the key and value in the combobox.

Comment: @Amit if @Bhakki sais is true then [I don't see any relevant constructor for combobox](http://lwuit.java.net/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/ComboBox.html) What you can do is, pass labels to Combobox. and maintain its value in a `Vector` and have a mapping based on the index

Answer (score 1):

Just create the bean class like set the key and value.
For example,

```
public void beanClass {

String value;
String key;

 public beanClass() {
} 
public void setValue(String value) {
this.value = value;
public void getValue() {
return value;
}
public void setValue(String key) {
this.key= key;
public void getKey() {
return key;
}
}
```

then create the `beanClass` array on your class and pass the Key's and Value's. then pass the `beanClass` array to `ComboBox`.

`comboBox.getSelectedItem()` returns the beanClass. So you can get the key and value from selected `beanClass`.